# Use cells to fill in the filepath for a SUMPRODUCT formula?

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

I am creating a SUMPRODUCT formula with a nested SIGN formula which helps to set criteria for which I want figures to be pulled from (similar to SUMIF or SUMIFS). Is there a way to have part of the formula refer to a cell/column that has a string, which is used to make up the filepath?

See below the example code.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((
'S:\Folder\[File.xlsm]Range-97-98'!$B$5:$N$5
=
B$7
))*((
'S:\Folder\[File.xlsm]Range-97-98'!$B$423:$N$423
)))
```

The worksheet "Range-97-98' as you can see is a short Year range. This is because the current row the Sumproduct formula is on is a row assigned for 1997-98 (cell A9 = "1997-98")

Is there a way to change that Worksheet in the filepath based on the trimmed cell value from A column? eg. A10 is "1998-99" therefore the SUMPRODUCT would be Range-98-99'!..., and A11 is "1999-00" and so on.

Comment: Take a look at the indirect function and the concatenate function and see if they can help you out.  One of the catches with indirect is that the references address needs to be an open workbook.

Comment: I am familiar with the Indirect function however being able to work on a closed workbook is the reason why I have elected to use the sumproduct formula over the sumif formula that was previously used.

Comment: The only other way I am aware of to manipulate the path of a range would be with a little bit of VBA which is not one of your tags

Comment: It's okay. What I've done instead was just used a bunch of substitute formulas in a separate worksheet to breakdown and replace parts of the filepath. It all works now. :)